# Zend_Dojo_Form Elements aren't proper working

Tags: javascript, php, zend-framework

Now I tried a bit around with `Zend_Dojo_Form`. The elements do not work like expected. The only element which is working is the checkBox.

To see for everybody here a screenshot:

[image]

Here a snippet of my formclass:

```
$this->addElement('DateTextBox','datum',array(
            'label' => 'datum',
            'datePattern' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
            'required' => 'true'
        ));
        $this->addElement('TimeTextBox','zeit',array(
            'label' => 'Uhrzeit',
            'timePattern' => 'HH:mm',
            'required' => 'true'
        ));
        $this->addElement('CheckBox','test',array(
            'label' => 'ja Nein',
            'checkedValue' => 'yes',
            'uncheckedValue' => 'nein',
            'checked' => 'true'
        ));
        $this->addElement('editor','test1',array(
            'label' => 'Editor',
            'plugins' => array('redo',
            'undo','|','bold','italic','underline'),
            'editActionInterval' => 2,
            'height' => '100px'
        ));
```

My form `extends Zend_Dojo_Form`

I want to use date and time, don't mind I tried the others also to see if Zend_Dojo is found.

The date and time elements don't drop down on click, they just show like in the screenshot an X and a second row.

EDIT:

I have the dojo like follows in my application.ini

```
resources.view.helperPath.Zend_Dojo_View_Helper = "Zend/Dojo/View/Helper"
```

In my layout.phtml:

```
if ($this->dojo()->isEnabled()){
    $this->dojo()->setCdnBase(Zend_Dojo::CDN_BASE_GOOGLE);
    $this->dojo()->setCdnDojoPath(Zend_Dojo::CDN_DOJO_PATH_GOOGLE);
    //$this->dojo()->requireModule('dijit.form.DateTextBox'); 
    echo $this->dojo();
}
```

Do I need something else?

Comment: can you check if dojo js library has been loaded?

Comment: how can I do that? I thought it is loaded because the checkBox works

Answer (score 0):

now it works, because I tried around to solve my errors the stylesheet was missing. So I added in my layout.phtml the stylesheet:

```
$this->dojo()->addStyleSheetModule('dijit.themes.tundra');
```